# Browsing specific website with specific DNS server

Tags: windows, networking, dns, routing

My OS is Windows 7 and i want to browse certain websites with certain dns server. Unfortunately our goverment banned twitter and youtube but i can get access to twitter when i change my dns server address from
Control Panel->Network and Internet->Network Connection->Local Area Connection->Properties>IPV4

I want to access vimeo without changing the dns server my isp provided and twitter with a different dns.

I guess this is possible. I found an article online how to do that in OSX but i don't know how to do that in Windows. Maybe with hosts file ? Sorry for my poor english.

http://blog.lexfriedman.com/post/2856721099/dns-servers-specific-domains

Comment: If your government has banned these website using a different DNS Server will unlikely work, and if it does, like recent cases it won't for very long.  Modifying the hosts file won't do anything.  How you set your connection to use a certain DNS provider is well documented, if its slow, then you should use a different provider.

Comment: I know how to set a certain dns provider. That was not my question i already wrote above how to do that. why are you stating the obvious. That reply doesn't help me with anything...

Comment: There isn't a reason to be rude. Your original question was less clear then the current revision is. Your only other alternative besides changing your DNS provider is to use a VPN. Of course if you experience performance problems when you change your DNS you will experience the same problems with a VPN.

Comment: I don't know of any automated solutions but you could try a [network switcher](https://www.google.com/search?q=switch+network+settings), or using [command line scripting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620173/how-can-i-set-change-dns-using-the-command-prompt-at-windows-8) for a possible one click solution.